# Expo vector icons not finding icon

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I'm using @expo/vector-icons and I'm using Ionicons, but the icon is not being displayed, I did everything following the documentation, but no icon is being displayed. Below is how it is being displayed on the device:

[image]

My code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import { Container, BackButton, BackButtonText } from './styles';

export function ForgotPassword() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  function goBack() {
    navigation.goBack();
  }

  return (
    <Container>
      <BackButton onPress={goBack}>
        <Ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" size={32} color="green" />
        <BackButtonText>Voltar</BackButtonText>
      </BackButton>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: Which device are you using? iOS or Android?

Comment: Strange, It's working for me on both. Here's an [iOS](https://i.imgur.com/e71PXr1.jpg) Screenshot and [Android](https://i.imgur.com/VxpvVyx.jpg) screenshot. [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@kartikeyvaish/ionicons) for the same

Comment: This is very strange, everything is installed correctly...